# How to Get List of All Likes Received Using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get list of how many "likes" I have received on all of the content I've posted on Facebook. For example, if 8 people liked a photo I posted, and 12 people liked a link I posted, I want to be able to access that information (e.g. post ID, number of likes, date of post, and a list of the likers (if possible).).

I can see how to get the *Pages* I like, but I want to see how many likes I've received. This is only needed for my own account, not anyone else's.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get that information:

```
/me/posts?fields=message,likes.summary(true)
```

API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts%3Ffields%3Dmessage%2Clikes.summary%28true%29&version=v2.6

(Of course you need to authorize with the `user_posts` permission)